# vueJS3 - How to trigger a function on event from sibling component

Tags: vue.js, events, fetch, vue-component, vuejs3

I want to trigger a function that `GET`s data from a http-server in a component, as soon as a button in a sibling component was pressed.

**SignUpForm.vue** has a button that triggers `customSubmit()`

```js
customSubmit(){
  //POST to API
  const user = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({newUser: this.newUser})
  };

  fetch("http://localhost:3080/api/user", user)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));

  this.$emit('refresh', true)

  this.clearForm();
}
```

The **parent component** looks as follows:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <SignUpForm @refresh="triggerRefresh($event)" />
    <!-- <Exp /> -->
    <Datatable :myRefresh="myRefresh" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import SignUpForm from "./components/SignUpForm.vue";
  import Datatable from "./components/Datatable.vue";
  import Exp from "./components/exp copy.vue";

  export default {
    name: "App",
    components: { Datatable, SignUpForm, Exp },
    data() {
      return {
        myRefresh: false,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      triggerRefresh(bool) {
        this.myRefresh = bool;
        console.log(this.myRefresh);
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Now i want the sibling component **Datatable.vue**
to `fetch` data from the server as soon, as `this.$emit('refresh', true)` is fired in `SignUpForm.vue`

Here's the script from `Datatable.vue`

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //Liste aller User
      userData: null,

      //temporärer User für das Details-Feld
      printUser: [{ name: "", email: "", number: "" }],

      //Property für den "read-Button"
      showDetails: false,

      //Property für den "Update-Button"
      readOnly: true,
    };
  },

  props: ["myRefresh"],

  methods: {
    pushFunction() {
      fetch("http://localhost:3080/api/users")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => (this.userData = data));
    },

    readData(k) {
      this.printUser.length = 0;
      this.showDetails = true;
      this.printUser.push(this.userData[k]);
    },

    editData(rowUser) {
      if (!rowUser.readOnly) {
        rowUser.readOnly = true;
        const user = {
          method: "PATCH",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify({ userData: this.userData }),
        };

        fetch("http://localhost:3080/api/users/patch", user)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => console.log(data));
      } else {
        rowUser.readOnly = false;
      }
    },

    deleteData(k) {
      fetch("http://localhost:3080/api/users/" + k, { method: "DELETE" }).catch(
        (err) => console.log(err)
      );

      this.pushFunction();
    },

    //blaue Reihen
    toggleHighlight(rowUser) {
      if (rowUser.readOnly === false) {
        return;
      }
      rowUser.isHighlight = !rowUser.isHighlight;
    },

    scrollDown() {
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3080/api/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => (this.userData = data));
  },
};
```

I really hope somebody can help a newbie out!

Comment: You could push an event to the parent, then update a model value in the parent, which is then bound to another component. The more you do such things via the parent, the more complex gets your application (and bound together). Therefore, you would usually use an external state for such things where you could push the value and retrieve it automatically in another component (via computed value). In Vue2, you would usually go for Vuex, but with Vue3 a very nice new way was introduced: The composition API which lets you outsource local state.

Comment: I will take a look into the composition API, thanks! 
Do you, by any chance, have  a specific solution for my code as well?

Comment: Set a watcher in Datatable for `myRefresh` and do not pass a boolean for that value but rather a generated value (e.g. `Math.random()`). Otherwise you would need first emit true, then wait a tick, then reset it to false. And you would need to check - in the watcher - if the value is true. By just setting a random value, the watch handler is executed when the value is changing. If you want to completely reload the component (not only refetching the data) you can also use the `:key=""` attribute of a component. As soon as this value changes, the component is rerendered.

Comment: You are not using VueJS3... take advantage of `setup`...

Answer (score 0):

Two considerations, *is it possible?* and *is it prudent?*

#### Is it possible?

Yes, it is and you can implement it couple different ways.

#### Is it prudent?

No.

If you're going down this road, most likely the architecture is ineffective. In an ideal setup, your components should be responsible for managing the view only. That means what the user sees and collecting their input. The *business logic* should not live in the components. So if you have things like ajax calls and you put them into your component, you've coupled the logic to the view. One possible issue is that if the component is re-added for some reason, any in-progress ajax calls could be disrupted in an unexpected manner. While such scenarios can be handled, the bigger issue IMHO is that that when you are coupling business logic with the view layer you are creating an application that becomes increasingly difficult to reason about; This problem you have with sending event between sibling components is just one example.

#### Other options

The most common way, though not the only way, of dealing with this is by using a *global store* via `Vuex`.

[image]

Instead of initializing the Ajax request from your component, you call the Vuex action.

The action would usually set loading state either using single state variable (ie `loadState=STATE.STARTED`) or using `isLoading=true`, except instead of assigning the variable, vuex would do it through a mutation, so `store.commit('setLoadState', STATE.LOADING)`. this will update the state in all components that are listening for changes in either the store directly or using a getter. Then the ajax request is made, and when it is done the store is updated again, either with `store.commit('setLoadState', STATE.ERROR)` or on success, `store.commit('setLoadState', STATE.DONE)` and `store.commit('setUsers', response)`. Then your components only need to listen for changes, you can display a spinner if `$store.loadState == STATE.LOADING`

As long as the data for the subsequent call is related to data specific to the component (like specific user ID or name) you can handle the next call from the component. Instead of triggering the second API request from the component by watching for an event from the sibling, you can have the component `watch` the vuex store or data for a change. Then when `$store.loadState` becomes `STATE.DONE`, you can trigger another action for the other API call. I would only do this though if there is any part of the data that is specific to the API call, otherwise if the call comes right after in all circumstances, you might as-well call it as part of the same action